# How to make a component fixed inside a div?

Tags: css

I want a div 'sticky' to stick inside other div 'scrollable', and scrollable is fixed to the viewport. This is what I have tried so far:

```css
 .outer {
     background-color: green;
     position: fixed;
     top: 30px;
     left: 30px;
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     overflow: auto;
 }
 .inner {
     background-color: blue;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 p {
     height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer" >
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I want the blue box to be always on the bottom of the scrollable div. I have been looking on other questions but I have not found an answer.

I also tried to make 'fixed' the blue box to simulate that behavior but the 'down' arrow of the scrollbar does not work, and that is just a hack, don't think is the way it should be done.
I tried using this css for `inner` class:

```
  .inner {
 background-color: blue;
 position: fixed;
 top: 230px;
 left: 30px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 }
```

```css
 .outer {
     background-color: green;
     position: fixed;
     top: 30px;
     left: 30px;
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     overflow: auto;
 }
 .inner {
     background-color: blue;
     position: fixed;
     top: 230px;
     left: 30px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 300px;
 }
 p {
     height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer" >
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <div class="inner"> </div>
</div>
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: You can do it with `position: sticky` however it is not standard(https://jsfiddle.net/n205jwkn/). You can fake it easily by putting the blue div under the scrollable div and updating the markup to accommodate the change

Comment: @Huangism So far that works fine, can you make an answer out of it?, but wait, what about the transform? what's that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky` but this is not a standard

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

sticky will work on chrome and FF, but probably not IE, test throughly before using

https://jsfiddle.net/n205jwkn/2/

```
.inner {
     background-color: blue;
     position: sticky;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

OR

you can fake it with a different kind of set up shown in this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n205jwkn/1/

CSS

```
.outer {
     background-color: green;
     position: fixed;
     top: 30px;
     left: 30px;
 }
 .container {
   height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     overflow: auto;
 }
 .inner {
     background-color: blue;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 p {
     height: 100px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer" >
  <div class="container">
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
  </div>

  <div class="inner" ></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an overall `container` and place the blue `div` as a sibling of your content, as in the following example:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
    <p> sample </p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```